# Is this allocation statement right for cllocationmanager?

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management, cllocationmanager

I have read through many sample codes and found that,

```
self.Location = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
```

this kind of allocation over a retained `Location` object is valid? this kind of memory management is it advisable??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your propery is retain or copy then you are over retained and the variable should be released, which looks strange... so if you want to do it in one line you would autorelease it.

Comment: shouldnt i do like this?? location = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init]; self.Location = location; [location release];

Comment: yeah or... self.property = [[Class new]autorelease];

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is perfect, I don't see any problem here.

As, you are using MRC,
You can go with

```
self.Location=[[[CLLocationManager alloc] init] autorelease];
```

or

```
 self.Location=[[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
```

and in the dealloc, `[Location release];`

Comment: shouldnt i do like this?? location = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init]; self.Location = location; [location release];

Comment: this will be automatically in autoreleased, in ARC.

Comment: I am not doing via ARC i am doing manual release for my project

Comment: for safer side, you can use autorelease while allocating

Comment: location = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.Location = location;                                                    [location release];

Comment: can i release it after assigning it?

Comment: **NO** As you assigned, you should not release it. Either you may copy or retain and then release it.

Comment: i am retaining it only so i can release it right?, i have mentioned in my post that i am retaining it clearly